# Can the preprocessor capitalize letters in a given symbol and output that as a new symbol?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'm wondering if the preprocessor (specifically the one shipped in Xcode's LLVM) is able to do something like this:

```
#define CAPS_SYMBOL(x) ...
```

where this preprocessor statement in code:

```
int CAPS_SYMBOL(lala) = 1;
```

would output the following valid compilable code:

```
int Lala = 1;
```

The end goal of what I want to do is to make a macro that does this, given that some mechanism for CAPS_SYMBOL exists:

```
#define MAKE_WEAK_VAR(x) __weak __typeof(x) weak ## CAPS_SYMBOL(x) = x
```

Is this possible? If so, how does one do it?

Comment: why do you care that its capitalized, if you're never going to see it?

Comment: I would care as it would define a variable that is used later on. MAKE_WEAK_VAR(blah) would define a weak variable called weakBlah that i could reference later.

Comment: oh i see, that would be really confusing if i read that. since i would never be able to look up that variables declaration. that sort of betrays the expectation of someone reading your code

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it's not a great practice; I have something similar that doesn't do the dynamic variable naming and just declares weakSelf in a macro which is a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the preprocessor can not capitalize tokens. But you could define

```
#define MAKE_WEAK_VAR(x) __weak __typeof(x) weak ## x = x
```

instead. Then for example

```
MAKE_WEAK_VAR(self);
```

expands to

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakself = self;
```

Comment: yeah, that's an option; i was hoping to make the macro conform to camelCase capitalization though. Oh well, thanks for the confirmation!